# Why am I getting ads in the webView of my Android application (I did not register for any)

Tags: java, android, firebase, webview, google-play-services

I am getting something like this in my webview.

Here is a screenshot of the ad:

[image]

Comment: The advertisement is part of the URL which you are trying to load. It has nothing to do with your code. Could you share the URL which you are trying to load?

Comment: I was using a webview url that was hosted in my server.

Comment: Please share your code. More details required to identify the issue.

Comment: WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
WebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
WebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
WebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
WebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
WebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
WebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
WebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
WebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
WebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

Comment: this is the config that I have given for the webview

Comment: This advertisement doesn't popup every time, please let me know if i need to share the complete code.

Comment: The issue was because the req url was "HTTP"